# Web API CORS Angular $resource

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2, angular-resource

I have a Web API constructed in VS2012 using MVC4 and Web API 2. The front end is developed in AngularJS using ui-grid. The VS2012 JavaScript editor is not really very friendly, so I am using JetBrains WebForm 9 to develop the front end. This means that every request to the backen is a CORS request.

In the front end I got it all working using $http but since this project, though useful, is being used by me to learn I decided to convert to use $resource instead. But the $http successfully used the GET, POST, OUT and DELETE interfaces in the backend so I know they all work.

However, when I convert the code to use $resource, the query works fine but the save does not. It yields the following error in the JaveScript console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:51274/api/series. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

It never gets as far as the POST, instead it fails after an OPTIONS call. Fiddler is running so I post the HttpRequest and the HttpResponse below. Remember, in the $http implementation the POST worked fine.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:51274/api/series HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:51274
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:63342
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:63342/AWSOrderEntry/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

and the response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcbWhvcnRvbi5ucmhcZG9jdW1lbnRzXHZpc3VhbCBzdHVkaW8gMjAxMlxQcm9qZWN0c1xBV1NPcmRlckVudHJ5XEFXU09yZGVyRW50cnlcYXBpXHNlcmllcw==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control_Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access_Control-Allow-Methods: *
Date: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 04:32:52 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I am assuming from this that $resource, before doing a CORS does a "pre-flight check" by sending the OPTIONS which effectively says can I POST against this URL? The answer appears to be YES and use can use the header Content-Type. B ut then $resource sees this and complains that it is not allowed to send Content-Type in the request.  So it issues a message and errors the call without ever issuing the POST. The Fiddler never shows the POST and the backend`enter code here` when in DEBUG mode doesn't halt on the POST request in the Controller.

The following is then entry in Web.config.

```
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control_Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
    <add name="Access_Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
```

It seems to me that either there is a bug in $resource or, and this is much more likely, I have done something really silly and don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an underscore rather than a dash in your Access-Control-Allowed-Headers header:
`Access-Control_Allow-Headers: Content-Type`

should be:

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have stared at those lines over and over and never saw the problem.